# non sentence ending な in this comedic conversation

Tags: copula, sentence-final-particles, particle-な

MC spots girls A and B who he recently got to know. C = childhood friend of MC.

> A「あ、先輩。こんにちは」
>
> MC「おう、A。Bも一緒か」
>
> B「何よ、アンタだってC先輩たちといつも一緒じゃない」
>
> MC「何だよ、仲良いなって意味で言っただけだぞ」
>
> B「アンタが言うとそう聞こえないのよね、不思議ー」
>
> MC「ヒネくれてんなー、さすがはレンチ**な**だけある」
>
> B「ヒネる工具**な**だけに？って、全然上手くないわよ！！」
>
> (MC) おお、意外にノリがいいな。

MC:「おう、A。Bも一緒か」

B:「What about it, aren't you always with C-sempai?」

MC:「Huh、I'm only talking in terms of how close you two seem.」

B:「If you say that, I don't hear it that way (feels like you were insinuating more), strange.」

MC:「Rebellious aren't you, as expected of just a wrench.」 (a play on ひねくる vs ひねくれる)

B:「As expected from a wrench tool？ That was not a good joke at all!!」

(MC) Unexpectedly she got the joke.

---

"仲良いな"って意味 and ヒネくれてんなー are normal sentence ending な, but how was ヒネくれてん abbreviated?

What are the な in レンチ**な**だけ and ヒネる工具**な**だけに?

Comment: `what are the な in レンチなだけ and ヒネる工具なだけに` -- The な's are the attributive form of the auxiliary (or the copula) 「だ」, and not the particle な. It's #1 in https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162228/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA/

Comment: why was this use here/ when would you choose to use this?

Comment: ^ そうですね...  明鏡国語辞典 says: `だけに〘連語〙➊...(語法) 名詞には、直接つける用法のほか、「…なだけに」「…であるだけに」の形でもいう。「まだ 子供だけに/まだ子供なだけに/子供であるだけに」`. 工具 is a noun, so you can do with or without the な. Both 「ヒネる工具だけに」 and 「ヒネる工具**な**だけに」 sound fine, and I don't see semantic difference here. And 明鏡 also gives examples: `だけ〘副助〙➏...「さすが音楽家だけのことはある」▹「…だけ（のことは）あって」の形で...`. レンチ is a noun, so you can do without the な, saying 「さすがはレンチだけ(のことは)ある」 .

Answer (score 2):

> are normal sentence ending な but what how was ヒネくれてん abbreviated?

てん is a short slang form to ている

> what are the な in
>   レンチなだけ and ヒネる工具なだけに?

According to The Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar, the pattern 
**（さすがに）~なだけのことはある**
is an evaluative comment on something contributing to a remarkable, expected result.
I presume なだけある is a short version of なだけのことはある...

So, the result in your case, is ひねくれる, and the natural reason contributing to this, is, that B is a レンチ.

I've found the same question asked also here, for reference to the short form:
https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/4278/

Comment: Re: "てん is a short slang form to ている", the contraction proceeds from ～ている → ～てる, and then only collapses to ～てん if the following word starts with a nasal or other voiced consonant.  For instance, やっているが → やってんが, but やっているけど → やってるけど.  Sometimes you'll still see やってんけど or similar, in which case the contraction includes a の: やっているのか → やってるのか → やってんのか → やってんか.

Comment: [i don't see anything pertaining to な with this construct in particular](https://gyazo.com/f93d770024929fdacccda42d5cde1d59)

Comment: @charu, please refer to the Formation (ii) section: Adj(na) + な/だった + だけのことはある

Comment: ^ `Adj(na) + な/だった + だけのことはある` <-- でも・・・ 「レンチ」「工具」って、na-adjective じゃなくて、名詞ですよね。。